# How can I send a calendar invitation from command-line using Mutt?

Tags: command-line, calendar, mutt

I want to be able to send calendar invitations from command-line using Mutt. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Calcurse to export an event

```
calcurse --export
```

copy-paste it into your Mutt email, and then change the content type to `text/calendar` using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

A more skilled Mutt user could probably create a neat macro for this.